# javascript only populating first input not second

Tags: javascript, html

hello im adding up inputs and they work when taking the amounts to the subtotal. However the page total at the bottom doesnt update with the sum of the tax and sub total. Any help would be great. Im new to javascript and im sure something is flying over my head

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
<tr class="info">
<td>Subtotal</td>
<td class="total" id="tot" for="tot">
<input class='form-control' type="total" id="total" onchange="myFunction1()" readonly>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tax</td>
<td class="taxtot" id="taxtot" for="taxtot">
<input class='form-control' type="taxt" id="taxtot" readonly>

</td>
</tr>
<tr class="info">
<td>Total Due</td>
<td class="thetot" id="thetot" for="thetot">
<input class='form-control' type="thetot" id="thetot" readonly>

</td>
</tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
        {
            var answer = document.getElementById('total');
            var n = 0
            var x = document.getElementById('itemprice1');
            var y = document.getElementById('itemprice2');
            var z = document.getElementById('itemprice3');
            var w = document.getElementById('itemprice4');
            var taxt = document.getElementById('taxtot');
            var thetot = document.getElementById('thetot');
                                                                    //var d = document.getElementsById('itemprice3');

                                                                    // parseFloat converts to values, otherwise you'll concatenate the strings.
    answer.value = parseFloat("0" + x.value ) + parseFloat("0" + y.value) + parseFloat("0" + z.value) + parseFloat("0" + w.value);
    //{
        //taxt.value = parseFloat(n.value + "0");
    //thetot.value = parseFloat("0" + answer.value);
//}
     // + d.value;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction1()
        {
        var answer = document.getElementById('total');
        var taxt = document.getElementById('taxtot');
        var thetot = document.getElementById('thetot');

        thetot.value = parseFloat("0" + answer.value) + parseFloat("0" + taxt.value);


}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post on Fiddle

Comment: why you  wrote 0 before values? If you dont use dot , I think it is unneccessary

Comment: We can't see the whole HTML, just the total and subtotal part, maybe the problem is right there, check it please.

Comment: as Yury says your id's must be unique, you have a td and input with id `taxtot` and `thetot`, and so in effect you are setting the value property on the td elements. Also why are you using a "for" attribute on a td? They are valid for label and output elements not td.

Comment: And note programatically changing an inputs value will not trigger the change event: http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/8MYXZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id attribute must be unique so remove the id from td elements (you don't need it) and leave it only on input elements.

Code:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr class="info">
        <td>Subtotal</td>
        <td class="total" for="tot">
            <input class='form-control' type="total" id="total" onchange="myFunction1()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tax</td>
        <td class="taxtot" for="taxtot">
            <input class='form-control' type="taxt" id="taxtot" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
        <td>Total Due</td>
        <td class="thetot" for="thetot">
            <input class='form-control' type="thetot" id="thetot" readonly>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/S2AP6/

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your code..

Your input type's do not exist.

You have 2 elements which have the same ID... `taxtot`

```
<td class="taxtot" id="taxtot" for="taxtot">
<input class='form-control' type="taxt" id="taxtot" readonly>
//AND
<td class="thetot" id="thetot" for="thetot">
<input class='form-control' type="thetot" id="thetot" readonly>
```

Which gives `undefined` when you do `document.getElementById('taxtot').value` as it's taking the first element with this ID, i.e the `td` element. And does not update the value of Total as its was meant for the `td` element.

And why putting `onchange` when the input fields are `readonly`?

The best way to make the total update is to put the function in tax:

```
<td class="taxtot" id="taxtot" for="taxtot">
<input class='form-control' type="text" id="tax" onblur="myFunction1()" readonly>
```